# Combining lists by identifying overlaps between their values and ensure uniqueness between lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have the following data structure:

```
{company_id: 
   [
      (set_id,[product_id,product_id,...]),
      (set_id,[product_id,product_id,...]),
      (set_id,[product_id,product_id,...])
      ,...
   ],
company_id:
   [
      (set_id,[product_id,product_id,...]),
      (set_id,[product_id,product_id,...]),
      (set_id,[product_id,product_id,...])
      ,...
   ],
}
```

A sample set of data may be:

```
{83: 
   [
      (128, []), 
      (129, [19283, 23837]), 
      (130, [29553]), 
      (133, [19283, 20070, 20072, 20087, 20095]), 
      (134, [20069, 20070, 20071, 20095, 20098])
   ],
84:
   [
      (145, [2322,2211]), 
      (146, [2333, 2211]), 
      (152, [2333])
   ],
}
```

What I need to achieve is:

```
{83: 
   [
      (128, []), 
      (130, [29553]), 
      (133, [19283, 20069, 20070, 20071, 20072, 20087, 20095, 20098, 23837])
   ],
84:
   [
      (145, [2322,2211, 2333])
   ],
}
```

The result is a list of tuples for each `company_id` where no `product_id` exists in another tuple's list of an `company_id`.

- It is ensured, that each `product_id` exists inside only one `company_id`'s list.
- It doesn't matter for which `set_id` the `product_id`'s are going to be merged into
- If no value in a tuple's list exists in any other tuple's list, keep it as it is and don't merge it with any other lists

I started to do some nested `for` loops already, but feel like it is too complex. Here is a (not working)  code of mine that doesn't include the deletion of already watched lists:

```
import copy

data = {83: [(128, []), (130, [29553]), (133, [19283, 20069, 20070, 20071, 20072, 20087, 20095, 20098, 23837])], 84:[(145, [2322,2211, 2333])],}

final_result = copy.deepcopy(data)
for company, val in data.items():
    for set in val:
        for x in final_result[company]:
            if any(item in x[1] for item in set[1]):
                x[1].extend(set[1])
                
print(final_result)
```

I would be happy if someone could provide me with a solution to my problem. Also happy to use `numpy` or `pandas` for it!

Comment: I don't see `owner_id` in your data

Comment: `It doesn't matter for which set_id the product_id's are going to be merged into` - if this is true, why not put the set of all `product_id` for a given `company_id` in the first `set_id` and leave the rest empty?  It seems like there are missing requirements

Comment: @anon01 added the remaining requirement and changed the the wrong wording

Comment: Show a [mcve] with the immediate problem you're trying to solve. Nesting it in a complex datastructure just distracts. Ask yourself if we need to see the outer dict, or know if there's more than one company at all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sadly this is the way I receive the data... and I hope that my little sample set of data makes the issue reproducible

Comment: @JoeBe. You can extract a representative example of the minimum portion they you're trying to solve. Please read [ask] and understand [mcve]

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for referencing these links. However, I really don't see the big difference between how I should ask my question and how I did it here. I have thousands of data points and I tried to provide a tiny snippet that reproduces the issue. I explain the requirements for the solution. I show what I coded so far. I provide an explanation of the data structure. The title explains the issue. Only thing that I may have not done is to put the explanation text first, but I thought it is better to see the data first to reference it in the text better. If I have to change that I can do.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't understand what you don't see but want to see.  He has provided sample input and output and specified rules - I think this question is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This meets your requirements as stated (not a unique solution).  It caches product_ids for each set_id, and filters out those already observed when moving to the next (set_id, product_ids) list items.

```
data = {83: 
       [
          (128, []), 
          (129, [19283, 23837]), 
          (130, [29553]), 
          (133, [19283, 20070, 20072, 20087, 20095]), 
          (134, [20069, 20070, 20071, 20095, 20098])
       ],
    84:
       [
          (145, [2322,2211]), 
          (146, [2333, 2211]), 
          (152, [2333])
       ],
    }

def clean_data_wrapper(data):
    for company_id, product_tuples in data.items():
        memo = set()
        revised_product_tuples = []
        for set_num, product_list in product_tuples:
            filtered_ids = set(product_list).difference(memo)
            revised_product_tuples.append((set_num, list(filtered_ids)))
            memo.update(filtered_ids)
        data[company_id] = revised_product_tuples
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charme. The moment you posted your answer I also came up with a solution (which is a bit longer than yours). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229322/8289724)

Answer (score 0):

While @anon01 worked [on his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229242/8289724) (which seems much better) I also worked out a solution:

```
import copy

data = {83: [(128, []), (130, [29553]), (133, [19283, 20069, 20070, 20071, 20072, 20087, 20095, 20098, 23837])], 84:[(145, [2322,2211, 2333])],}

final_result = copy.deepcopy(data)
final_result2 = {}
for company, val in data.items():
    for set in val:
        for x in final_result[company]:
            if any(item in x[1] for item in set[1]):
                x[1].extend(set[1])
            
    for x in final_result[company]:
        if company not in final_result2:
            final_result2[company] = [set(x[1])]
        else:
            final_result2[company].append(set(x[1]))
print(final_result2)
```